# Angle between two lines in Maple

Tags: coordinates, line, angle, maple

I am trying to find the angle between two lines in Maple, but I keep getting this error.

```
`restart:
with(Student[MultivariateCalculus]):
a:=Line([0,0],[0,2]);
                   a := << Line 1 >>
b:=Line([0,0],[2,0]);
                   b := << Line 2 >>
Angle(x,y);
Error, invalid input: Student:-MultivariateCalculus:-Angle expects its 1st 
argument, x, to be of type {Student:-MultivariateCalculus:-Line, Student:-
MultivariateCalculus:-Plane, Vector}, but received x`
```

I know that the answer to this angle is 90 degrees, I just gave a simple example so I can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you assigned to `a` and `b` (rather than `x` and `y`) then try the command,

```
Angle(a, b);
```

For example (this is from an actual session),

```
restart;
with(Student[MultivariateCalculus]):

a:=Line([0,0],[0,2]);

              a := << Line 1 >>

b:=Line([0,0],[2,0]);

              b := << Line 2 >>

Angle(a,b);

                     1   
                     - Pi
                     2   

Angle(a,b) * 180/Pi;

                     90
```

Comment: Sorry I just added it incorrectly on here, I had what you were saying but it still gives me the same error- even when I change the square brackets [] to <> it gives that error. I used this website for help but it doesn’t work for me https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student%2FMultivariateCalculus%2FAngle

Comment: I apologize, I tried it now and it worked. Maybe I was confused before. Thank you so much for this.